# Loop Iteration Analysis Part 2

Tags: algorithm, big-o, analysis

To clarify before I begin, this is NOT homework but rather I am studying for my exam. I have given solutions for the questions below. I would like some constructive feedback.

Thanks for the feedback for whoever left it in my last question. Below I have given in detail solutions to why i think the answer is so.

Find running time in terms of O(n) notation.

```
int y=0;
for(int j=1; j*j<=n; j++)// runs from 1->j=sqrt(n) times
    y++; //constant - c
```

Therefore, run time is `c x n^1/2 = O(n^1/2)`

Q2.

```
int b=0;
for(int i=n; i>0; i--) //runs from n->1
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) // runs from 0 to i
        b=b+5; //constant
```

for each value of `j (1,2...,n)` inner loop runs i times constant = `ci`.
- `nc+(n-1)+...+2c+1c = c(n+..+2+1) = cn(n+1)/2 = O(n^2)` run time.

Q3.

```
int y=1;
int j=0;
for(j=1; j<=2n; j=j+2) //runs 2n times, increments by 2
    y=y+i; //constant c

int s=0;
for(i=1; i<=j; i++) // not a nested for loop, therefore runs n times
    s++;
```

running time: `O(n)`

Q4.

```
int x=0; //constant
for(int i=1; i<=n; i=i*3) //runs log_3 (n) times
{ 
    if(i%2 != 0) // for values above will always be 1

    for(int j=0; j<i; j++) // runs from 0 to log_3(n)
        x++;
}
```

so we have `clog_3(n)xclog_3(n) = O(log_3(n))^2`

Comment: First three is out of doubt. But the forth... May be not `O(log_3(n))^2` but `O(mlog_3(n))`, because the inner loop iterates over `0-m` (actually `0-i`) items instead of `0-log3(n)`. I mean, yes, inner loop goes exactly only `O(log_3(n))` times, but not from `0-log_3(n)` for sure.

Comment: care to elaborate a bit? still kinda confused. thx

Comment: Q4 will never terminate the way it is (unless n=1) because `i` will always be 1 since `1^3`=1

Comment: Ok, your inner loop's complexity is of n order, neither n^2 nor log[x](n). Even not N, but a bit smaller but in `n` order though (and therefore can't be just skipped). So, in this case you should take an `m`: `O(mlog3(n))`.

Comment: @Raze2dust where did you find `1^3`? It's only `1*3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first three are out of doubt (I believe, all are correct).
But with Q4 there is a problem.

Your answer is a little bit incorrect. Definitely, the result is not `O(log_3(n))^2`. The case is in the inner loop, which goes exactly only `O(log_3(n))` times. And, not from `0-log_3(n)` but from `0-m` (where `m` is obviously correlated to `i`).

Assuming all above, I think the right answer is `O(mlog3(n))`. But if someone think that i was wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

```
The loops can be thought of as two summations

Summation ( i from 1 to lg_3(n) ) * Summation (j = 0 to i-1) [1 operation]
= Summation (i = 1 to lg_3 (n) (i)
= 1 + 2 + 3....lg_3(n) terms
= lg_3(n) [ lg_3(n) + 1] /2
= O (lg_3(n)] ^2
```